# Identification between splitting fields of irreducible polynomial and simple extensions of algebraic element

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I read somewhere (and would like to ask for confirmation) saying that simple extensions of an algebraic element are always of the form $K[X]/(m)$ where $m$ is the minimal polynomial (which is the only irreducible polynomial?) containing that element. This appears to me to be exactly the same (up to isomorphism) as the splitting field of its minimal polynomial. Is it true that there is a natural identification between them two?

Also, may I conclude hence, that for any irreducible polynomial $m$ in $K[X]$ and its roots $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n\in\overline{K}$,
we have $K(\alpha_1)=(\cong) ...= K(\alpha_n)\cong K[X]/(m)$?
In particular (I saw similar claims, not sure why), in the case of a separable extension, $\{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n\}$ as well as $\{\alpha_i^1, ..., \alpha_i^n\}, \forall i$ always form bases of the extension?

Comment: I'm afraid you seem to have some confusions about the terminology. We extend a field by adjoining an algebraic element to it, but it sounds very strange to say that we extend an algebraic element. Nothing happens to that element :-) Anyway, the answer ... depends. Any one of the fields $K(\alpha_i)$ is, indeed, isomorphic to $K[X]/\langle m(X)\rangle$, but they are usually not splitting fields. The splitting field should contain **all** the zeros of $m(X)$ in $\overline{K}$. Whether that is the case depends on $m(X)$.

Comment: For example when $K=\Bbb{Q}$ and $m(X)=X^2-2$ we do get the splitting field. The roots of $m(X)$ are $x_1=\sqrt2$ and $x_2=-\sqrt2$, and when we adjoin $x_1$ we get $x_2$ free of charge. OTOH when $m(X)=X^3-2$, and we adjoin $x_1=\root3\of2$, we won't get the other two roots, becaue they are complex numbers and the field $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ only contains real numbers.

Comment: Look at actual examples, of degree greater than $2$.  Try $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and $\mathbf Q(i\sqrt[4]{2})$. Both are isomorphic to $\mathbf Q[x]/(x^4-2)$ but neither is a splitting field of $x^4 - 2$ over $\mathbf Q$ since $x^4 - 2$ has 4 roots but only two of them (the real roots) lie in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$. By being isomorphic to this, $\mathbf Q(i\sqrt[4]{2})$ also contains just two roots of $x^4 - 2$ (namely $\pm i\sqrt[4]{2}$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see. Regarding terminology, what about $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, $\pi$ is not root to any $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$, but the extension is a simple one (but not algebraic?)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the example of $m(X)=X^3-2$. Let's say the other two roots are $z_1, z_2\in\mathbb{C}$. According to your claim, $\mathbb{Q}(z_1)\cong \mathbb{Q}(z_2)\cong\mathbb{Q}[X]/(m(X))$ but those fields contain only one root for $X^3-2$, and this serves as an example of splitting field of minimal polynomial not being in the form I had assumed. However, doesn't this contradict with the fact that the extension (being a splitting field) is normal?

Comment: Both of you have mentioned in your comments the fact that splitting field of an irreducible polynomial isn't necessarily in the form of $K[X]/(m)$. However, I was originally misled by the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field#Constructing_splitting_fields), and also the fact that every splitting field is normal. Isn't this a contradiction? Further, how should a splitting field look like in general?

Comment: What is true (over a perfect field $K$) that the splitting field $L$ of $m(X)\in K[X]$ over $K$ is of the form $L=K[X]/\langle p(X)\rangle$ for **some** irreducible polynomial $p(X)$. This is because as a finite extension of a perfect field $L$ is a simple extension. But, we don't necessarily have $p(X)=m(X)$. Mind you, in this case $L$ is also the splitting field of $p(X)$, but more often than $p(X)$ has higher degree than $m(X)$.

Comment: And.. $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ is not the splitting field of any polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$.  The splitting field of a polynomial over a perfect field is always normal, but $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ isn't normal.

Comment: I see. I guess due to the previous confusion I somehow assumed that simple extensions would also necessarily be normal, which isn't the case (maybe not even in a perfect field, since in your example $L$ was normal only because it's already by definition a splitting field in the first place). But regarding your last comment: it doesn't matter whether it's over a perfect field, a splitting field is always normal, right?